# Can we express an AR(1) process as follows?

Tags: expected-value, autoregressive, conditional-expectation

If $X_t$ follows an AR(1) process as follows
\begin{equation}
X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

Would it be correct to express the above as

\begin{equation}
X_t=\mathbb{E}\{X_t\mid X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

If the above is correct, would it then be possible to express

\begin{eqnarray}
P[X_t<0]&=&P[\mathbb{E}\{X_t\mid X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\}+\varepsilon_t<0]\\
&=&P[\varepsilon_t<-\mathbb{E}\{X_t\mid X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\}]
\end{eqnarray}
or am I completely off?

Comment: It's true ( with a negative on the expectation )  but not really so helpful because all you're really saying is that $X_t < 0$ when $\epsilon_{t} < -1.0 \times \rho X_{t-1}$.

Comment: Is there anyway else around this? I mean to evaluate that probability would i somehow be able to fix $X_{t-1}$ at its realisation at $t-1$, so that the argument of that probability is fixed? @mlofton

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But then you have to assume normality of the $\epsilon_t$ ( okay, I guess ) and know it's mean ( I guess assume zero ) and  also it's standard deviation. In practical situations, the standard deviation is estimated so you never really know it perfectly.